# Arabic problems with converting html to PDF using ITextRenderer

Tags: itext, flying-saucer

When I use ITextRenderer converting html to PDF.this is my code

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
String inputFile = "C://Users//Administrator//Desktop//aaa2.html";
String url = new File(inputFile).toURI().toURL().toString();
renderer.setDocument(url);
renderer.getSharedContext().setReplacedElementFactory(
        new B64ImgReplacedElementFactory());
    // 解决阿拉伯语问题
ITextFontResolver fontResolver = renderer.getFontResolver();
try {
    fontResolver.addFont("C://Users//Administrator//Desktop//arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
} catch (DocumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

renderer.layout();
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C://Users//Administrator//Desktop//HTMLasPDF.pdf");
renderer.createPDF(outputStream, true);
/*PdfWriter writer = renderer.getWriter();

writer.open();
writer.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
OutputStream outputStream2 = new FileOutputStream(  "C://Users//Administrator//Desktop//HTMLasPDFcopy.txt");
renderer.createPDF(outputStream2);*/
renderer.finishPDF();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Actual PDF Result: [image]

Expected PDF Result: [image]

How to make arabic ligature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the way to convert pdf by using wkhtmltopdf.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this properly (I assume using iText, since your post is tagged as such), you should use

- [iText7](https://itextpdf.com/itext-7-core)
- [pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML) (to convert HTML to PDF)
- [pdfCalligraph](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph) (to handle Arabic ligatures properly)
- a font that supports these features (as indicated by another answer)

For an example, please consult the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml), more specifically the following FAQ item: [How to convert HTML containing Arabic/Hebrew characters to PDF?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/how-convert-html-containing-arabichebrew-characters-pdf)

You need fonts that contain the glyphs you need, e.g.:

```
public static final String[] FONTS = {
    "src/main/resources/fonts/noto/NotoSans-Regular.ttf",
    "src/main/resources/fonts/noto/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf",
    "src/main/resources/fonts/noto/NotoSansHebrew-Regular.ttf"
};
```

And you need a `FontProvider` that knows how to find these fonts in the `ConverterProperties`:

```
public void createPdf(String src, String[] fonts, String dest) throws IOException {
    ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
    FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
    for (String font : fonts) {
        FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(font);
        fontProvider.addFont(fontProgram);
    }
    properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(src), new File(dest), properties);
}
```

Note that the text will come out all wrong if you don't have the [pdfCalligraph add-on](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph). That add-on didn't exist at the time Flying Saucer was created, hence you can't use Flying Saucer for converting documents with text in Arabic, Hindi, Telugu,... Read the [pdFCalligraph white paper](https://developers.itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/attachments/Whitepaper_pdf2Data_2017.pdf) if you want to know more about ligatures.

Comment: Indeed, the OP is using a third party tool called "Flying Saucer." Flying Saucer uses an old iText version that doesn't support ligatures. See [How to convert HTML containing Arabic/Hebrew characters to PDF?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/how-convert-html-containing-arabichebrew-characters-pdf) in the FAQ section of the official HTML to PDF tutorial.

Comment: I change the way to convert pdf by using wkhtmltopdf.

Answer (score 0):

Greek characters seemed to be omitted; they didn’t show up in the document.

> In flying saucer the generated PDF uses some kind of  default
>   (probably Helvetica) font, that contains a very limited character set,
>   that obviously does not contain the Greek code page. [link](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2015/02/15/unicode-characters-dropped-in-pdf-files-generated-with-itext-and-flying-saucer/)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed for me By Just upgrading the Library from "itext7.pdfhtml" v4.0.5 to v5.0.0 and Then I add two more Add-on "itext7.pdfcalligraph v4.0.0" and "itext7.bouncy-castle-fips-adapter v8.0.0".

and it's Fixed for me in .NET 7.0

[Calligraph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIBQe.png)