# ITextSharp writing RTL words wrongly

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation, right-to-left

I am experiencing something strange while writing some names text using ITextSharp – I am writing some text namely “حبیب الله ځاځی” 
I attempt to write this string onto the PDF using ITextSharp 5.5.13 using the code below:

```
var fp = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), “arial.ttf”);
var bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(fp, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

…..

```
IList<AcroFields.FieldPosition> fieldPositions = frm.GetFieldPositions(fieldName);
AcroFields.FieldPosition fieldPosition = fieldPositions[0];
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rec1 = fieldPosition.position;
var sizef = ColumnText.FitText(new Font(bf), ourstring, rec1, font_size, PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);

Phrase px = new Phrase();
Chunk chunk = new Chunk(ourstring, new Font(bf, sizef));
px.Add(chunk);
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                                            px, rec1.Right, rec1.Bottom - bf.GetDescentPoint(ourstring, sizef), 0, PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL,ColumnText.AR_LIG);
```

…
While debugging I have confirmed that the name is being sent correctly

But when I open the resulting document – the text is displayed wrongly as seen below
[image]

When I open this file in Adobe Acrobat Pro with a view of editing – I can see that the assigned font is correct i.e. Arial
 [image]
If I change it to some other font and and then back to Arial – the text is displayed correctly as it should be

[image]
I have attempted various combinations  the Arabic options ColumnText.AR_XXX and nothing changes

Does any one have an idea on what is going on here?

Comment: I see that you are using a *maintenance* version of a version of iText that is no longer supported. Maintenance versions are created for paying customers who aren't ready to migrate to the most recent version of iText yet. Non-paying users should use iText 7 because iText 5 is no longer supported for them. Note that the name **iTextSharp** was abandoned two years ago in favor of **iText for .NET** (which explains why you couldn't tag your question as an iTextSharp question).

Comment: Also: iText 5 only had limited support for Arabic; you explicitly had to tell iText that you wanted to change the run direction and make the ligatures. With iText 7, Arabic is supported in a more general way. Once you [activate the pdfCalligraph add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39054803/1622493), iText will detect Arabic based on the Unicode value of the characters, and automatically change the writing system. That's interesting if you want to [convert Arabic HTML to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47811983/1622493).

Comment: See this [HTML to PDF FAQ entry](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/how-convert-html-containing-arabichebrew-characters-pdf) to discover how to save an enormous amount of time to achieve the requirements of your project. This is the [official pdfCalligraph page](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph) and there's also a [comprehensive white paper about pdfCalligraph](https://developers.itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/attachments/Whitepaper_pdfCalligraph_2017.pdf).

Comment: The previous three comments all boil down to: you should upgrade to iText 7 + the pdfCalligraph add-on.